# Angular 2 - material 2 checkbox - checkbox [checked] by default

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-material2

I'm using `md-checkbox` in a `FormArray`.

```
private protocolArray: FormArray = new FormArray([
    new FormControl('tcp'),
    new FormControl('udp')
]);

<div class="form-group" formArrayName="protocol">
      <md-checkbox formControlName="0" [checked]="true">TCP</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox formControlName="1" [checked]="false">UDP</md-checkbox>
</div>
```

When it renders both are checked by default. If I get rid of the `md-checkbox` and make it a normal `input type="checkbox"` things render perfectly.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that FormArray only takes boolean values so by instantianting it with 'tcp' or 'udp' it type casted them to `true`. I had to tweak my code to work around it, but creating the array with true or false fixed it.

Final code:

```
private protocolArray: FormArray = new FormArray([
    new FormControl(true),
    new FormControl(false)
]);

<div class="form-group" formArrayName="protocol">
     <md-checkbox formControlName="0" >TCP</md-checkbox>
     <md-checkbox formControlName="1" >UDP</md-checkbox>
</div>
```